# "Python has stopped working" - PyGame on Windows

Tags: windows, pygame, python-3.4

Having trouble getting my basic game to start up - maybe 1 in 5 games start up - the others end immediately with "Python has stopped working".

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to use older python - 3.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an older version on python as suggested by furas. When I run your code on my laptop it starts up fine, I am using python 2.7

If you are using python 3.4.x pygame will not work, its latest version only runs on 3.3.x.

I have run your program multiple times and it runs every time with a box that has the caption "Hello World".

Comment: Python3.3 didn't work either. I ended up switching to booting in Ubuntu because it just wouldn't work in Windows.

Comment: Oh and as for Python 3.4 - there's a binary for it listed here - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame.